# SMTPServerDisconnected at /users/password_reset/ Connection unexpectedly closed, why am I getting this error in 2022?

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I am trying to send emails using sendgrids SMTP relay. I created a apikey, added this into my settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'jajamensanson@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mysendgridpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

When I try to send the email, I get this error:
SMTPServerDisconnected at /users/password_reset/
Connection unexpectedly closed

Anyone have an answer to this? Also, just for your info, I am using the django for beginners book.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` should be your SendGrid API Key, with permission to send mail, not your SendGrid Password.

One other thing to check, I see that you are using a gmail address as your from email. Make sure you have [verified that address as single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) otherwise SendGrid won't deliver the email. For production we recommend using your own domain and performing [domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).